# Where is ConstraintLayout source code located?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Where can I find the source code for the android `ConstraintLayout`? I can't find it in the support framework repository and even in Google search.

Comment: Please star this serious [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67791487)!

Answer (score 8):

Its source code is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/sherpa/+/studio-3.0/constraintlayout/src/main/java/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.java

The Android SDK search extension adds a "View source" button on d.android.com reference, which helped me to get this link

Comment: How about after migration to `androidx`?

Comment: @arekolek There's no AndroidX sources available yet, because it is still using support libraries, and published as an AndroidX version using jetifier to map the package names.

Comment: Is there any way constraint layout library versions can be associated back to the exact source code the release was built from? It seems there are not Git tags matching constraint layout library releases.

Comment: In the last few minutes there has an encouraging response from google to the issue I noted in my above comment!!!

Comment: where is the response,please?

Comment: It's in reply to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the **AndroidX** version of **ConstraintLayout** is found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/ui/ui-layout/src/main/java/androidx/ui/layout/ConstraintLayout.kt