# Android Studio can't download and attach source codes for some library

Tags: android, android-studio

in my case, it's like this [source code like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xuo0X.png)

then, I click "download source" , but see this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26R68.png)

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Collections.java:4189)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleAttachSourcesProvider.getSourceFile(GradleAttachSourcesProvider.java:160)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleAttachSourcesProvider.access$100(GradleAttachSourcesProvider.java:59)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.util.GradleAttachSourcesProvider$1$1.onSuccess(GradleAttachSourcesProvider.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$7.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:943)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$9.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:972)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:736)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$4.run(CoreProgressManager.java:395)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm sure my network is ok. And for many other libraries this is OK.SO,I'm confused of this.Can someone tell me why problem happened ? I also want to know how android studio download source code and attach them , is there any document for this？

Comment: anyone answer this question ?

Comment: I have exact same problem with MotionLayout (which extends ConstraintLayout) but it happens with other classes also. I have asked the same (more general) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925243/where-is-the-residual-offline-documentation-for-androidx). Did you ever fix?

Comment: not yet, very confused. LOL

Comment: Duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690904/where-is-constraintlayout-source-code-located).

Answer (score 0):

For some unknown reason, the current *ConstraintLayout* dependency (see your *build.gradle*) **does not ship with source**! I am using a 'hack':

(A) Use your browser to save the official documentation to a file whose path depends on your SDK location. ( You will have to create any empty intermediate folders).

```
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout
file:///[your SDK]/docs/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.html
```

(B) From Android Studio ***Project*** view click ***External Files*** and navigate to your dependency. eg:

```
Gradle: androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3@aar
```

(C) Right click  -> ***Library properties*** -> ***Specify documentation URL***:

```
file:///[your SDK]/docs/reference
```

Not great, but better than nothing. I repeated it for *MotionLayout* and a few others.

Comment: the question is about code source, not documentation..