# Why am I seeing only decompiled source for an official android class?

Tags: android-studio, androidx

Please note that I have previously installed *Documentation for Android SDK* via AS 3.5.2 SDK manager

Consider the following inconsistent behavior whilst editing java source code ...

```
import android.app.Fragment;    // Deprecated!
```

If I hover over *Fragment* I get extensive, beautifully-formatted JavaDoc help. Furthermore, at the bottom of the Documentation window there is an option *External documentation for `Fragment`* that links to a local file:

```
file:///home/daz/Android/Sdk/docs/reference/android/app/Fragment.html
```

Now, **moving to androidX ...**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout;
```

If I hover over *Fragment* I get an abbreviated help which directs me to the 'framework' documentation. (Less elegant but acceptable)

But if I hover over *MotionLayout* I get **nothing** except a reference to

```
Gradle: androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3@aar
```

If I go to the declaration I get decompiled source and whenever I try to code a method I have to search the internet for the parameters. All attempts to *Choose* or *Download* sources while viewing the decompiled source have failed.

I consider this unacceptable - good documentation exists and I would like to get to it easily!

```
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/motion/widget/MotionLayout
```

I appreciate that *MotionLayout* was a comparatively recent (2018) announcement but it is not an isolated case.

Why is this happening? Why is Android Studio unable to find official Android source code?

Comment: Please **unHold** this question! The recently-edited title makes what is being asked clear as day.

Comment: It's a great question, too bad no one is allowed to answer.

Comment: @AndrewKoster Don't know what you did - but thank-you! Question taken off **hold** a few hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Determine if the source .jar was shipped with the **.aar**:

Example: **androidx.fragment.app.Fragment**
Assumes External Library: **Gradle: androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0@aar**

EITHER Right-click the external library (from *Project* view) --> Library Properties ...
OR Navigate to :

```
.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/androidx.fragment/fragment/1.1.0
```

Expand the subfolders and confirm something like

```
b9ebb04df2cb0cad4419af3c658690bc82aa5706/fragment-1.1.0-sources.jar
```

Example: **androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout**
Assumes External Library: **Gradle: androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta3@aar**

By  using the above method, you will rapidly determine that no *sources.jar* exists. (You will only see the **.aar** and the **.pom**)

Establishing why not is beyond the scope of this question.

Until some-one provides a more satisfactory answer, you may like to try this [grubby hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58932184/2376004).

**Update 21Nov2019**:
If your problem relates to ConstraintLayout or MotionLayout please star this known [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67791487).

Comment: I would move the "update 21Nov2019" to a comment rather than answer updates. In that way I would vote up the comment.